# Customizing Windows 8's Windows Explorer's sidebar

Tags: windows, windows-8, windows-explorer

I want to remove "My PC" and my username from the Windows Explorer sidebar. I just want a bunch of Favorites and the network devices. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the tool **[FolderTweak for Win8.1](http://elvenbone.deviantart.com/art/FolderTweak-for-Win8-1-404879892)**

[image]

or the tool **[This PC Tweaker](http://winaero.com/comment.php?comment.news.213)**

[image]

Maybe they help you to customize the Explorer the way you want it.